# Calculating vector perpendicular to a plane tangent to a sphere

Tags: geometry, vectors

We have a point $P$, which is connected to n points (red points).

[image]

How can we calculate an imaginary sphere as the red points are on its surface (an approximation)? Then, how can we find the plane tangent to the sphere at point $P$ to calculate the vector perpendicular to that plane (obviously crossing the centre of the imaginary sphere)?

We have the green and red points, and want to calculate $PC$ vector.

Comment: a tangent direction is perpendicular to the vector position

Answer (score 1):

Everything reduces to calculating the center of the sphere. Let's call $(x_i,y_i,z_i)$ the coordinates of red and green points, and $(x_c,y_c,z_c)$ the coordinates of the center of the sphere. Then, for a perfect sphere, $$(x_i-x_c)^2+(y_i-y_c)^2+(z_i-z_c)^2=R_2$$
So if you have 4 non-coplanar points, you find the center and the radius. If you have more, and the sphere is not perfect, then one can use a least square approach. Take $$S=\sum_i\left((x_i-x_c)^2+(y_i-y_c)^2+(z_i-z_c)^2-R_2\right)^2$$ and minimize it with respect to the radius and the coordinates of the center:
$$\frac{\partial S}{\partial x_c}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial y_c}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial z_c}=\frac{\partial S}{\partial R}=0$$
Solve the above equations.